How do I Automatic Weigh paint to only the selected bone
I'm following a rigging tutorial and the person automatic weight paint the tongue to a rigify rig with no problem, but when I try to do it the tongue is influenced by other bones. I try to fix it through the vertex group but some of the bones are not showing. So I'm trying to auto weight paint the tongue to only the tongue bones.
Please help
Here is the file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d-KzTd30FuHp7l-3l2z1unicDz4j466u/view?usp=sharing

You do have only the tongue bones selected, yes?

Maybe select the vertices of the tongue and go into the dropdown panel on the right of the vertex groups list and Remove from All Groups? Then assign to the correct vertex groups?

I've already tried those but it still didn't work
